# CSV Files and Web Services

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, csv, asmx

Hi Everyone sorry to bother you. I run a small blog and I'm just trying to create a webservice that allows for words to be input and their meaning to be shown. I am self taught (recently) at C# code and think I'm getting better but I have hit a snag. This is my current working code;

SORRY JUST NOTICED I HAD COPY/PASTED WRONG CODE. UPDATED IT NOW

```
  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace MyWebService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Service1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public class Table
        {
            private Dictionary<string, string> _regionTimeValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            private String _words;

            public Table(String words)
            {
                _words = words;
            }

            public void AddValue(string key, string value)
            {
                _wordsTimeValues.Add(key, value);
            }
        }

        public class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Dictionary<string, Table> tables = new Dictionary<string, Table>();

                using (var reader = new StreamReader("Data.csv"))
                {
                    // First line contains column names.
                    var columnNames = reader.ReadLine().Split(',');
                    for (int i = 1; i < columnNames.Length; ++i)
                    {
                        var columnName = columnNames[i];
                        tables.Add(columnName, new Table(columnName));
                    }

                    var line = reader.ReadLine();
                    while (line != null)
                    {
                        var columns = line.Split(',');

                        for (int i = 1; i < columns.Length; ++i)
                        {
                            var table = tables[columnNames[i]];
                            table.AddValue(columns[0], double.Parse(columns[i]));
                        }

                        line = reader.ReadLine();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I thought it would be as simple as moving code from one application to another as I have similar application working within a console application but trying to do it on a webservice has had me pulling my hair out.

Comment: What exactly is the snag?

Comment: Does this even compile? What is `words` in `getWords()`? And `public string words()` doesn't appear to be returning anything.

Comment: What are you expecting these methods to do? As they currently stand the application would not compile, let alone run.  The method `words()` does not return a value, and `getWords()` references a variable that has not been defined.

Comment: Yeah, nothing is happening when I try to run it. It compiles but then nothing appears on my webpage. I'm trying to get the words from data.csv. Input 1 word and the meaning comes out. e.g input World output Earth

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You are using the legacy ASMX technology, which should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is mixing console application code with web application code.  The two run in different ways.

In the most basic sense,

The console application required a method usually `static void Main()` that is the first method run when the application is started.

Web applications run only the methods on a given page that correspond the requested action.

You have code from a console application in a web page, this is not going to work by simply copy paste.  You need to modify the code a bit.  The code sample you have provided is not clear in it's purpose, so I cannot provide a sample for you.